# Can an extension installed on Firefox access data from another browser, say Chrome?

Tags: browser, google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions, browser-addons, privacy

Forgive my lack of understanding with regards to browsers. I am just starting my journey learning to code and I am setting up a live server extension to practise html.

I am a bit distrustful of using extensions considering the high level of access that they have to read/write and access data on a browser. The browser I use for my personal stuff (emails, accounts, youtube etc) has no extensions except for adblocker. I have a blank vanilla version of another browser (firefox) for using live server and any other possible extensions that i may need in the future.

My question is whether or not this one browser with extensions that can access & or read/write data has the same priviledges across to my other browsers. Is it solely the browser that the extension is installed on or can they 'cross communicate/see' another browsers webpage data?

Maybe I'm being overly paranoid but I would like to keep the browser that I use for my personal stuff secure and not compromise it with an extension. I am also aware that you shouldn't just download any extension and should be certain that you trust it before installing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer : Cross-browser pollution is not possible.

In more detail, after two decades of fighting viruses, browsers have
become pretty secure.

An extension in a browser is very limited in what it can do.
Not only is it isolated from the disk and operating system, able to access
stuff only via the browser's API and what it allows, but it's also isolated
from other extensions.

Every extension is allocated its own private storage, which only it can
access, and is also allowed access to some global data of the browser
that it's permitted to use.

The full answer is that your scheme of using two browsers is pretty
secure.